# Dutch zipcode table rates doesn't work if added characters

Tags: magento-1, table-rates, delivery

I have added some zipcodes to my tablerates.
We deliver only in the Netherlands.
I would like to add delivery costs when a zipcode is (for example) "3141 AA"

I noticed that this only works when clients fill in 3141 on the zipcode and when the zipcode is "3141 AA" it doesn't work anymore...
But in the Netherlands zipcodes are with 2 characters like 1234AB or 1234 AB.
So this method doesn't work! I guess because USA isn't using characters in their zipcodes?

Is there any way to fix this?

My tablerates CSV:

```
NLD,*,3141,0.0000,7.5000  
NLD,*,3142,0.0000,7.5000
NLD,*,3143,0.0000,7.5000
```

I have tried this but doesn't work:

```
NLD,*,3141*,0.0000,7.5000
```

Comment: check out my updated answer, i believe it's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the following module, i believe it might seems helpful to your condition. 
Give it a try, there is the link of the module:

[MatrixRate](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps/extension/604/webshopapps-matrixrate--the-original-multiple-table-rate-solution--certified-bug-free)

or check this out i believe it suits you better than the module:

[Nl post code](http://magento.dijksterhuis.org/review-postcode-nl-magento-plugin/)

i am posting also one more module but the this one is not for free check it out:

[Dutch PostNL](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dutch-postnl-parcelware-manual-rates-packages-and-letters-national-and-international-with-letter-logic-letterbox-post-brievenbus-pakje-post.html)

Comment: As a Dutch dev I can vouch for this module. It accepts part of the postcode

Comment: Thanks but I rather don't use this module. I'm thinking about changing the zipcode fields. Just make it a 4 digit formfield and add a new field for the two characters. Do you know if its possible to add this second custom field and show it on all places you can think of?

Comment: @Sander , does the module can set of ranges like: 2300-2315 and 4500 - 4507

Comment: i updated my answer so give it a try

Comment: @user123  I think it's possible. last time I had to do this was 1,5 years ago so it's a bit foggy. We used it for a shipping rate for the Waddeneilanden

Comment: Vsld, Nice module but that still doesn't fix my problem :( thanks anyway :)
@Sander, thanks, I probably have to give MatrixRate a try

Comment: user123 did you followed the instructions in Nl post code link?

Comment: Vsld, that module automaticly finds the zipcode based on street address, but that doesn't fix the zipcode only 4 numbers problem so the delivery costs change for a couple of zipcodes.Or I'm missing something.

Comment: i putted another module to check out, give it a try if you want.

Comment: Ah thx but they deliver them selves. Only for Rotterdam and some places (zipcodes) arround Rotterdam clients need to pay 7,50 delivery costs.